# renaming 000.gz file to loganme.gz

Tags: logging, rename, .gz

I have written automation to export cloudwatch logs from cloud watch loggroups to s3 bucket . The exported logs are placed in 0000.gz file in s3 bucket .I want to rename all
000.gz file to stream name.gz .how can i achieve this

I have written automation to export cloudwatch logs from cloud watch loggroups to s3 bucket . The exported logs are placed in 0000.gz file in s3 bucket .I want to rename all
000.gz file to stream name.gz .